# remove all characters except tokenized words from a string using python

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, unicode

I am python-beginner. I've performed all NLP-steps to clean my text. Finally I stemmed my string then remove all stopwords from it.
The problem is that when I stemmed the text, I have a letter 'u' before every stemmed word. I want to remove this letter from whole text.

Here is the input:

> ['other', 'program', u'crash', 'win', 'restart', 'or', 'reboot', 'then', u'bookmark', 'and', u'person', u'set', u'delet', 'happend', 'to', 'me', 'three', 'time', u'mani', u'program', 'are', u'open', 'and', 'one', u'crash', 'i', 'reboot', 'the', 'system', 'when', 'the', 'system', u'restart', 'mozilla', 's', u'bookmark', 'and', u'person', u'set', u'prefer', u'save', u'login', u'pass', u'vanish', 'the', u'prefer', 'are', 'set', 'back', 'to', 'the', 'default', u'seem', 'to', 'me', 'that', 'mozilla', u'ha', 'been', u'interupt', u'write', u'save', u'it', 'current', u'set', 'when', 'i', u'reboot', u'thu', u'eras', 'it']

Required output:

> ['other', 'program', 'crash', 'win', 'restart', 'or', 'reboot', 'then', 'bookmark', 'and', 'person', 'set', 'delet', 'happend', 'to', 'me', 'three', 'time', 'mani', 'program', 'are', 'open', 'and', 'one', 'crash', 'i', 'reboot', 'the', 'system', 'when', 'the', 'system', 'restart', 'mozilla', 's', 'bookmark', 'and', 'person', 'set', 'prefer', 'save', 'login', 'pass', 'vanish', 'the', 'prefer', 'are', 'set', 'back', 'to', 'the', 'default', 'seem', 'to', 'me', 'that', 'mozilla', u'ha', 'been', 'interupt', 'write', 'save', 'it', 'current', 'set', 'when', 'i', 'reboot', 'thu', 'eras', 'it']

This is my code...

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
porter = PorterStemmer()
stemmed = [porter.stem(word) for word in token]
print stemmed
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this code? What does it not do that you want it to do, what does it do that you _don't_ want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The u's indicate unicode strings in Python 2. Encode them all as ascii like this to make the output look like you want:

```
stemmed_normalized = [element.encode("ascii") for element in stemmed]
print stemmed_normalized
```

Or you could do it in one step as

```
[porter.stem(word).encode("ascii") for word in token]
```